# Is there any way to start OneTimeWorkRequest from different application?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, foreground-service, android-12

I have 2 applications, let's say applications A and B.

Current situation :

- When I receive some action in application A via broadcast receiver then I start one **foreground service** of Application B to perform some task. below is the code snippet to start my service :

> Intent i = new Intent();
> i.setComponent(newComponentName("com.example.xyz","com.example.xyz.ForegroundService"));
> context.startForegroundService(i);

The above code is working fine as per expectation.

Now we want to give **support for Android 12** in our application :

- As per google behavior changes we are not being able to start foreground service from the background. So we have to replace the service with Workmanager in application B.
- Now my concern is how can I start the **OneTimeWorkRequest** from application A.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about AIDL in Android? Create a Service, define .aidl interface and bind to this service in application A

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).